# Displaying Content Text of a Cell Vertically in GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, vertical-text

I have a GridView and want to display content text of cells vertically in it.
I want it to be just like vertical headers as mentioned in [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q526800).
For clarity, I want to emphasise that I want to implement this to cells in records, not header cells.

Thank you

Edit: Sorry for missing information. I'm trying to implement this to a C# WinForm project. I couldn't do anything because the topics for displaying cells vertically in GridView are for only Header Cells.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Also, is it WPF, WinForms, ASP.Net?

Comment: Sorry for missing information. It is C# WinForms application

Answer (score 0):

Handle event `CustomDrawCell` for your `GridView`.
Take the same approach as described [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q352492) for the headers.

Comment: "For clarity, I want to emphasise that I want to implement this to cells in records, not header cells."

Comment: Read my answer again. Hint: check the name of the event.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I misunderstood. Well, I appriciate that If you can give me an example code snippet for this. I couldn't figure it out.
Thanks..